# How to reduce processing time for list-dict key reference

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

The following code generates a dict and converts it to a list in the dict key order(in Python >= 3.7). And, get dict-key from list-index.

I want to reduce processing time for this code. The processing time on my PC is about **1.5** seconds.

Is there any better way?(is it possible to refer the index of dict directly for speeding up?)

```
from random import random
import time
from numba import jit

# ---------------
# 1.5 sec
# ---------------
N = 100000
dic_test = {}
for i in range(N):
    dic_test[str(i) + "_ID" ] = (random()*1000, random()*1000, random()*1000)

# dict to list
li_test = list(dic_test.values())

start = time.time()

# ~~ A process outside Python ~~
# e.g. get output
li_index = [10001,10004,30101,50001,80009,90001,90011]

# get dict-key from list
@jit
def getkey(dic_test={}, li_index=[]):
    dic_key = {}
    for i in li_index:
        for j,k in enumerate(dic_test.keys()):
            if j == i:
                dic_key[k] = True
    return dic_key

dic_key = getkey(dic_test, li_index)

elapsed_time = time.time() - start
print ("elapsed_time:{0}".format(elapsed_time) + "[sec]")
```

Comment: why? There is no need to use an idext to index into a dict. use the key. If you want to know which keys are in a dict use `set.intersection()`. What problem do you need to solve with this code=?

Comment: A `dict` comprehension would also probably be faster than the `for` loop you're using, if only marginally: `dic_test = {str(i)+"_ID":(random()*1000, random()*1000, random()*1000) for i in range(N)}`. In general code looking for improvements like this might be better suited to [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than StackOverflow

Comment: Also, do not use [mutable args as defaults](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/mutable_default_value_as_argument.html) (list, set, dict, etc...)

Comment: Thanks...Perhaps the core of my question is that I want to get dict-key with the dictionary registration order as the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to get fancy I saw speed increases using `operator.itemgetter`. And you can just get all values to be `True` using `dict.fromkeys`

```
def getkey(dic_test={}, li_index={}):
    return dict.fromkeys(itemgetter(*li_index)(list(dic_test)), True)
```

This took `0.006012678146362305` for me

In comparison, your method took `0.18927502632141113`.

**Edit**

Spent some time thinking about this and came up with this using `itertools.islice` and it seems 2x faster than my above method:

```
def getkey(dic_test={}, li_index=[]):
    return {next(islice(dic_test, i, None)): True for i in li_index}
```

Time: `0.003183126449584961`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, also I edited my answer as I figured out a faster way, please confirm this for you and I will edit.

Comment: Many thanks!! The second way was faster than the first. I will look into 'islice'.

Answer (score 0):

reduce a loop layer

rewrite

```
for j,k in enumerate(dic_test.keys()):
            if j == i:
                dic_key[k] = True
```

to

```
dic_key[list(dic_test.keys())[i]] = True # python3
# or "dic_key[dic_test.keys()[i]] = True" for  python2
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it's really bad practice to use mutable default arguments. The reason being is that they are compiled at function definition time, or once. They are not re-allocated each time you call the function, so you can get behavior you might not expect:

```py
def func(a=[]):
    a.append(4)
    print(a)


x = []

func(x)
[4]
func()
[4]
func()
[4,4]
print(x)
[4,4]
```

The modifications made to the default of `a` are kept on subsequent calls.

Now, on to your code. You require `li_index`, so don't give it a default. By doing that you imply that it's optional, when in reality, it needs to be there or the for loop will never execute. Likewise with `dic_test`:

```py
def getkey(dic_test, li_index):
    dic_key = {}
    for i in li_index:
        for j,k in enumerate(dic_test.keys()):
            if j == i:
                dic_key[k] = True
    return dic_key
```

Since you already know how the keys are constructed (the index plus `'_ID'`), construct the key in the same fashion to do the lookup

```py
def getkey(dic_test, li_index):
    dic_key = {}
    for i in li_index:
        dic_key[f'{i}_ID'] = True
    return dic_key
```

Or, as a dict comprehension:

```py
def getkey(dic_test, li_index):
    return {f'{i}_ID': True for i in li_index if f'{i}_ID' in dic_test}
```

This way you are just leveraging the dictionary api directly, which is fast and readable, while avoiding unnecessary loops